# Using Ajax $_GET Variables As A Filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using Datatables Editor to populate a grid and want to filter it using different "WHERE" clauses.  My code is as follows:

> **jQuery**

```
// Valid Customer Accounts
$('#lnkValidCustomers').click(function () {
    // Redraw Grid
    customersTable.ajax.url('dataGridQuery.php?varCurrentCustomers=y&varInvalidCustomers=n').load();
});
// Invalid Customer Accounts
$('#lnkInvalidCustomers').click(function () {
    // Redraw Grid
    customersTable.ajax.url('dataGridQuery.php?varCurrentCustomers=n&varInvalidCustomers=y').load();
});
//All Customer Accounts
$('#lnkShowAllCustomers').click(function () {
    // Redraw Grid
    customersTable.ajax.url('dataGridQuery.php?varCurrentCustomers=y&varInvalidCustomers=y').load();
});
```

> **PHP**

```
// Database Fields
$editor = Editor::inst( $db, 'tblCustomers', 'customerID' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'customerID' ),
        Field::inst( 'customerName' ),
        Field::inst( 'customerNotValidDate' )
    );
// Where Clauses
if (isset($_GET['varCurrentCustomers']) && $_GET['varCurrentCustomers']=='y' && isset($_GET['varInvalidCustomers']) && $_GET['varInvalidCustomers']=='n') {  // All Valid Customers. 
    // Apply Filter
    $editor
        ->where('tblCustomers.customerNotValidDate', '', '=' );
} else if (isset($_GET['varCurrentCustomers']) && $_GET['varCurrentCustomers']=='n' && isset($_GET['varInvalidCustomers']) && $_GET['varInvalidCustomers']=='y') {  // All Invalid Customers.
    // Apply Filter
    $editor
        ->where( 'tblCustomers.customerNotValidDate', '', '!=' );
} else if (isset($_GET['varCurrentCustomers']) && $_GET['varCurrentCustomers']=='y' && isset($_GET['varInvalidCustomers']) && $_GET['varInvalidCustomers']=='y') {  // All Customers.
    // Apply Filter
    // No Filter
}
// Process Json
$editor
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

The problem I have is that the $_GET variables repeat and therefore not applying the desired WHERE clause.  Below is a console example of the parameter results:

> **Console**

```
gridNumber  3
varCurrentCustomers y
varCurrentCustomers n
varInvalidCustomers y
varInvalidCustomers n
```

I think the problem involves attempting to use the PHP $_GET parameters as jQuery variables; please let me know.  Any help in this regard is appreciated.  I am a self taught amateur web developer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$editor
    ->process($_GET)
    ->json();
```

is missing the values in "where"

Comment: Made that change however received the same results.